# Environment variable not set in container when using `environment` key

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Following [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files), I tried setting an environment variable with `-e TC=3` and in the compose file like so:

```
services:
  balancer:
    environment:
      - TC=3
```

But the variable is not set when the container is run.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using:

- docker-compose 1.23.1, build b02f1306
- Docker 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

Comment: how do you know the env is not set?

Answer (score -1):

The way you are setting the environment is correct. With this compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  test:
    environment:
      - HELLO=WORLD
    image: alpine
    command: env
```

I got this output

```
$ docker-compose -f test-compose.yml up
Creating network "sandbox_default" with the default driver
Creating sandbox_test_1 ... done
Attaching to sandbox_test_1
test_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
test_1  | HOSTNAME=e2eb1a0da23e
test_1  | HELLO=WORLD
test_1  | HOME=/root
sandbox_test_1 exited with code 0
```

If you want to be able to override a variable written in compose file, then you need to use `${var_name}` syntax, e.g.

```
environment:
  - HELLO=${hello_value}
```